# Какие посоветуете анализаторы трафика для Android?

Tags: android, веб-программирование, android-studio

В данный момент занимаюсь разработкой приложения для сервиса, который имеет своё апи, но не предоставляет его в публичный доступ. У сервиса имеется веб-морда, с помощью которой удалось воспроизвести авторизацию, но более расширенная логика находится на стороне мобильного клиента. Мне нужно узнать когда и какие заголовки отправляет приложение, поэтому хотел спросить, есть ли какие-нибудь средства перехвата? Может какой-нибудь плагин для Android Studio, или же может существует приложение на подобии WireShark?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dans.apps.webd&hl=ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для анализа http трафика отлично подходит решения (HTTP proxy): Charles или Fiddler2.
Также можете добавить свой сертификат и прослушивать трафик https, удобно и быстро.

Хорошая статья, где все действия описаны детально: https://habrahabr.ru/company/infopulse/blog/156711/

Comment: Премного благодарен, замечательный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

- Рутануть девайс, поставить linux, поставить WireShark
- Поставить [шашлык](http://www.shashlik.io), запускать в нем, на трафик смотреть через тот же wireshark
- Пустить трафик с девайса через свое устройство, на котором уже есть wireshark

Comment: Весьма и весьма костыльные решения для простого получения трафика.